# How to save the content of a structure to a file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, fopen, fgets

I have a given structure. I read all the characters of a txt-file and save it to a multidimensional array (lines) that i defined within the struct. Then I want to hand the struct variable over to a function which should then print all the characters to another txt-file.

Thats what I have:

```
typedef struct _content {
    int length;
    char **lines;    // multidimensional array
} content_t;


int curline = 0;     //global variables
int curchar = 0;
```

...

```
struct _content inhalt;
c = fgetc(ptr);
```

...

```
void write_content(char *filename, content_t *content)
{
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(filename, "a");

    printf("\nWriting Char Nr. %d in line: %d", curchar, curline);

    fputc(content->lines[curline][curchar], pFile);

    printf("\nJust wrote char Nr. %d in line: %d !", curchar, curline);

}
```

...

```
    while(c != EOF)     
    {
        inhalt.lines[curline][curchar] = c;

        //where I call the function write_content:
        write_content("write-file.txt", &inhalt);

        if(c == '\n')      
        {
            inhalt.length++;      
            curline++;      
            inhalt.lines[curline] = malloc(255);
            curchar = 0;
        }
        else
        {
        curchar++;
        }
        c = fgetc(ptr);     
        printf("%c", c);    

    }
```

The last output is: "just wrote char Nr. 36 in line: 22"

But the last char written into the file is Nr 0 in line 10...

Comment: What is the variable `content`? How do you access members of a *pointer* to a structure (as opposed to a non-pointer structure object, like you do now)?

Comment: Also, you do declare the function `write_content` before you call it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `content` is a variable of type content_t which is defined in the head of function write_content, I don't know...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did not, but I have changed it right now so that it is declared before I call it. The warning is gone, the error is still there

Comment: No, `content` is a ***pointer*** to `content_t`. I'm sorry for maybe sounding condescending, but please go back to your book, tutorial or class notes to read about member assess for pointers to structures, and about the "arrow" operator `->`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a pointer to your struct so you need to use `fputc(content->lines[curline][curchar], pFile)`.

Btw: If your lines are null-terminated you can use `fputs(content->lines[curline], pFile)`

Also @Someprogrammerdude is right you should define `write_content` prior to calling it.

Refering to the comments:

```
void write_content(char *filename, content_t *content)
{
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(filename, "a");

    for(int line = 0; line <= curline; line++){
        for(int c = 0; content->lines[line][c] != 0; c++){ // because 0 terminates the string
            printf("\nWriting Char Nr. %d in line: %d", c, line);
            fputc(content->lines[line][c], pFile);
        }
    }
    fclose(pFile);

}
// ...

while(c != EOF){
    inhalt.lines[curline][curchar] = c;

    if (c == '\n')      
    {
        inhalt.lines[curline][curchar+1] = 0; // ensure null termination
        inhalt.length++;      
        curline++;      
        inhalt.lines[curline] = malloc(255);
        curchar = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        curchar++;
    }
    c = fgetc(ptr);     
    printf("%c", c);    
} 
//where I call the function write_content:
write_content("write-file.txt", &inhalt);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This has solved my problem. However, the fuction fputc only writes out the characters till curline = 10 to the txt.file. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Could you please add the loops you're using to the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks- I just added them to the question.

Comment: You should read everything into your struct and after that write it to the file, or just write the one char into the file directly. Because currently you are opening the file for every character again. Also you should **always** close a file after using it.